# Excel .delete & .clearcontents stop sub

Tags: excel, vba

I had a weird problem: lines like

```
rows("1:1000000").delete
```

and

```
rows("1:1000000").clearcontents
```

stop executed and exited the subs.
There was no error messages and error handling did not get any error number.
In debug mode the line got executed and then all and the next thing was just no macro running, exactly like the line meant "end sub".
I googled it, found nothing.
Tried this macro on other computer all to the same result.
There is no protected cells, no spreadsheet and workbook events.
Eventually i deleted all the modules in the files and all the subs in the same module and the code run through. Then closed the file without saving, re-opened it and everything worked fine.
My guess is there was something that switched back to normal somewhere in Excel guts.
Any idea what it could be? I am afraid the problem may come back sometime.

UPDATE: the problem reappeared again and disappeared after running another macro in another file

UPDATE2: full code of the sub is here:

```
Sub GenRep()
Application.EnableEvents = True
Sheets("rep").Activate
On Error Resume Next
Rows("3:1000000").Delete 'this line breaks execution, no further lines are executed, no error code nor warning messages
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Err: " & Err.Number
NLines% = Sheets("db").Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Row
Rows("2:" & NLines).FillDown
End Sub
```

I commented the line which breaks execution

Comment: Can you try to look for `Application.EnableEvents` not set back to default value?

Comment: What's some of the code before/after that?

Comment: as others said, usr application.enableevents=true,... and the error probably comes from a worksheet_selectionchange or other event... a whole project search of word end or stop might help too.

Comment: @RomcelGeluz. I checked Aplication.EnableEvents, it's True
Also I inserted this line in the beginning of the sub to no effect at all:
'Application.EnableEvents = True'

Comment: Is that the *only code* in the entire workbook? Remove the `On Error` line.  I was able to run this without any errors, and using `F8` it executes the `Row().Delete` line and moves on to the `If Err.Number ...`  line.  Also, probably unrelated to the issue, but instead of `.Activate`, remove that line and just do `Sheets("rep").Rows("3:1000000").Delete.  Also, does the `NLines%` not throw an error? It does for me, so I added `Dim NLines as Long` and just use `NLines = Sheets...`.

Comment: @BruceWayne. I've tried removing `On Error...`. Same result. This is the only procedure that does not work. Also I've tried substituting `.Delete` with `.ClearContents`. Still does not work. Other procedures work just fine. `NLines` used to work before. Now it just does not get to that line. Also after the procedure exits on the line `.Delete` the VBE header starts flashing as if it goes through some other procedures, can't tell which though, it flashes too fast, even in break mode. I tried to insert breakpoint in every single procedure heading in the file and personal xlsb. No difference(

Comment: @BruceWayne And adding `Sheets("rep").` instead of `.Activate` makes no difference too(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sheet1.Range(Rows(1), Rows(1000000)).EntireRow.Delete
Sheet1.Range(Rows(1), Rows(1000000)).ClearContents
```

Comment: no luck, run-time error 424: object required
tried both lines separately to the same result
the code looks fine to me though

Comment: Instead of `Sheet1.` try to use `Worksheets("YourWorksheetName").`

Comment: Created new workbook, entered this code:  
`Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.Range(Rows(1), Rows(1000000)).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Range(Rows(1), Rows(1000000)).ClearContents
    Debug.Print Time
End Sub`  
No errors, no warnings, just current time never gets printed.  
It exits on line 2 quietly. If i comment line 2, it exits on line 3. Period.

Comment: So you have the immediate window activated with `str + g` and run throught the code with `f8`? So if i do the same it just works fine for me and the time gets printed.

Comment: not in my case, unfortunately(  This is what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Which Excel version are u using?

Comment: 2013 32-bit version